# Which is most common/correct "come in" or "step in"?

Tags: expressions

Which is most common and correct ot use; "come in" or "step in"? And is there a difference between these?

I want to use it in the scenario where someone is welcome to take a look into a house (from a realtor perspective).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

While they're both correct, `Come in` sounds a whole lot better than `Step in`.

The difference, when said as you've suggested, is that unlike `come in`, `step in` sounds like an order rather than a request.

Also, `step in` is rarely used as a complete statement. I've heard `(Please) step inside` used as a request but never just `Step in`.

Comment: I'd say *[Please] step inside [sir]* is more of a dated / formal / deferential ***invitation*** than "request" (more likely to be a facetious usage today than "natural English"). But essentially you're right here.

Answer (score 2):

If you were welcoming someone in, you would say "Come in".

(A possible exception to this is the phrase "Step into my office" which simply means "Come into my office")

You wouldn't tend to use "Step in" on its own as a welcome.

You would also tend to only use it in a larger sentence when the action involved walking down a step, or a short distance (eg to "step into a boat") or when someone wanted you to take just a single step, and no more, as in "Step into line".